# How to pass an argument in the sbatch command line?

Tags: parameter-passing, slurm

I would like to pass an argument into the sbatch command line.

### RHO_COR.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -o job-%A_task.out
#SBATCH --job-name=paral_cor
#SBATCH --partition=normal
#SBATCH --time=1-00:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=200G
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=16
#SBATCH --array=1-10

#Set up whatever package we need to run with

module load gcc/8.1.0 openblas/0.3.3 R

# SET UP DIRECTORIES

OUTPUT="$HOME"/PROJET_M2/data/$(date +"%Y%m%d")_parallel_nodes_test
mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"

export FILENAME="$HOME"/vipailler/PROJET_M2/bin/RHO_COR.R

subset=$((SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID))
file="$HOME"/PROJET_M2/raw/truelength2.prok2.uniref2.rares.tsv 

#Run the program

echo "Start job :"`date` >> "$OUTPUT"/"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID".txt
echo "Start job :"`date`

echo PWD $PWD

Rscript $FILENAME --file $file --subset $subset   > "$OUTPUT"/"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID"

wait


echo "Stop job : "`date` >> "$OUTPUT"/"$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID".txt
echo "Stop job : "`date`
```

I execute this code with :

`sbatch --partition normal --array 1-10 RHO_COR.sh`

What I would like to get is to use the  `file` argument into the command line above, which looks like `sbatch --partition normal --array 1-10 --file name_of_my_file RHO_COR.sh`

I don't want to specify the name of my file into the Slurm code, but into the `sbatch` command line, in order to never change this Slurm code.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass an argument after the script as if you were running it directly on the shell like this:

```
sbatch --partition normal --array 1-10 RHO_COR.sh name_of_my_file
```

And then the argument will be available inside the shell script as `$1`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Moreover, I'd like to pass as argument the number of arrays. I mean, the number of arrays I choose depends of the number of columns of my file (I can compute 55.000 columns on each array). My file has 817.000 columns, so I need 817k/55k ~ 15 arrays. So, I have created a variable `nb_arrays` in R which stores the number of arrays needed. I don't know if it possible to pass this argument like that `sbatch --partition normal --array 1-nb_arrays RHO_COR.sh name_of_my_file`

Comment: @VPailler You can use the environment variable `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_COUNT` set by slurm in the script that will contain the number of tasks in the job array

Comment: Yes, but actually, I don't want to rewrite my slurm code. That's why I want to use the variable `nb_arrays` which is computed automatically.  If in my R code, I create an argument like this : `opt$number=nb_arrays`  ;  and in my slurm code I do `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_COUNT=number` , does it make sense?

Comment: @VPailler I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, but I don't think that modifying the SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_COUNT makes sense inside the slurm code. Can you describe a little more the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Actually, what I just want to get is a "automatic" slurm code. I mean, with one array (=one node) of my cluster, I can compute up to 55.000 correlations of my matrix. My matrix has 820.000 columns, so I need 15 arrays. But if I want to use another file, for example with 550.000 columns, I will need 10 arrays. And that's my problem : I don't want to rewrite my slurm code with #SBATCH --array=1-10 but that the slurm code compute "automatically" the number of arrays needed.. If it is possible?